# How do you output the correct value for Chart.js Radar graph on label?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a table full of values:

```
Data     Val   Max
Data1 ... 3 ... 4
Data2 ... 2 ... 4
Data3 ... 3 ... 5
Data4 ... 5 ... 5
Data5 ... 2 ... 5
```

It is not enough to simple use [3,2,3,5,2] as my data set, because the max values for each is different.  So in order to do it properly the data is worked out as:

```
val/max
```

This now provides a set of values as:

```
Data      Val
Data1 ... .75
Data2 ... .5
Data3 ... .6
... and so on.
```

I have modified the hover label using:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>"
```

which removes the value from the hover label.  I then set up the label to be:

```
label + ' (' + val + ')'
```

This works well if you are dealing with a single set of data, however I will be handling multiple datasets in a single graph.  So what I really need is the label and the val to appear when you hover over the area.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have chatted with the client and they have agreed to use percentages rather than values, which makes more sense to me.